# jQuery Toggle not toggling at all

Tags: jquery

I have a simple website and I want to have a button to toggle between hiding and showing some text but so far everything I've tried hasn't worked.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <div class="background">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="testjavascript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <button id='hideshow'>Hide/Show Methodology</button>
        <div id="methodology" class="methodology">
            some form
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hideshow').click(function(){
        $('#methodology').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: your code is working perfectly! check the js fiddle link I put it here. https://jsfiddle.net/p5wkvrj9/

Comment: hmm yea it's weird. When I paste my work on JSfiddle it works but some reason it doesn't work when I load it up on chrome. I'll do a little more investigating. Thanks for your help!

Comment: when you have such error, you need to check the developer console in chrome or any other browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to first include the jQ library before your js file.

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="testjavascript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="background">
      <button id='hideshow'>Hide/Show Methodology</button>
      <div id="methodology" class="methodology">
        some form
      </div>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JQ code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hideshow').click(function(){
        $('#methodology').toggle();
    });
});
```